# When to use 従え or 従い?

Tags: grammar, imperatives

I found this example sentence in the Internet.

> [郷]{ごう}に[入]{い}っては[郷]{ごう}に**従え**と学んできました。
>   I have learned to do as the Romans when in Rome.

What I don't understand is, why use 従え? Shouldn't it be 従い?
Is there any difference in meaning between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

従え is an imperative form of 従う. Cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_verb_conjugation#Imperative

従え = "(please) do follow the rules of this place (郷)."

I guess it is similar to 従いなさい, though I've never read it in this form.